# Eloquent model add extra column by default

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called `Book` and I want to add an extra column to the default SQL.

At the moment the default sql looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `books`
```

But I want the default SQL to look like this:

```
SELECT *, "Hello" as `greeting` FROM `books`
```

So that I can do the following:

```
// in a controller function...
$book = Book::find(1);
echo $book->greeting; // Hello

$books = Book::all();
foreach($books as $book){
    echo $book->greeting; // Hello
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Why would you just not add that to the class definition itself rather than pretending this comes from SQL dynamically? It seems like you would, in essence, be hiding the property away from where it should truly be defined.

Comment: This is a simplified example. What I'm trying to do is actually add a new `score` attribute to my model. The `score` attribute is calculated as a sum of votes in another table. The resulting SQL is quite complicated and I didn't want it to detract from the question, which was how to add extra SQL columns to a model's default query.

Comment: Why would you then not relate the book model to the score model for this purpose? Yo also would probably get much more relevant answers to your actual use case if you actually explained that use case in your question.

Comment: A book's score is calculated as a SUM of the `vote_amount` column in the `votes` table (one book might have many votes). What I want to do is be able to end up doing something like this: `Book::orderBy('score', 'asc')->get()`. I couldn't find a way to do this through a relationship.

Comment: You would define hasMany and hasOne relations in each model, then you would do something like  `Book::find(1)->scores()->groupBy('book_id')->get(arrat('field1', 'field2', DB::RAW('SUM(score)'));`

Comment: @MikeBrant This is a very valid question, and indeed a very potent one at that. Your solution requires at least 2 database calls (as I understand the Eloquent engine to work) which could be performance-hitting if your book club is the size of Amazon's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though I wonder what the reason behind this is, you could override `newQuery` in your model

```
public function newQuery(){
    $query = parent::newQuery();
    return $query->selectRaw('*, "Hello" AS greeting');
}
```

Another way would be to use a [scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes):

```
public function scopeWithGreeting($query){
    return $query->selectRaw('*, "Hello" AS greeting');
}
```

Usage:

```
$book = Book::withGreeting()->find(1);
```

If you really want the scope every time, you can use a [global scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes) so you don't have to call `withGreeting` all the time.

Comment: That `scopeWith...` looks like it might be a viable way to achieve what I'm looking to do! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need more information... By the way you can call your scope anything you want. Just prepend `scope` for the method name

Comment: I wish you hadn't predicated that with "Even though I wonder...".  There are a million-and-one reasons that changing the SQL statement is better than letting Laravel do the Legwork. Nevertheless, your answer is the best solution I've come across yet.  `newQuery()` seems to do it all!

Answer (score 2):

Use [an accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators). This one returns 'Hello' for `$book->greeting` if the model doesn't have a greeting set:

```
public function getGreetingAttribute($value) {
  if(empty($value)) { return 'Hello'; } else { return $value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically want this extra attribute to come from the SQL query.

Comment: @ThomasClayson Why do you care, out of curiosity?

Comment: @ceejayoz [See the OPs comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324963/eloquent-model-add-extra-column-by-default/28325110#comment44997926_28324963)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$appends` Here is the example

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['greeting'];

    public function getGreetingAttribute()
    {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}
```

You don't need to write any SQL for this see more https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L59-L64

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ORM woud not be able to manage that well enough so you are going to get into trouble sooner than later, if you can not modify your book model but still wnat to accomplish that , i suggest you create a new model pointing to a view constructed with

```
SELECT *, 'Hello' as `greeting` FROM `books`
```

Comment: This is an idea. However, the problem with this is that you can't then use the same model to update the view (because views aren't updatable on the whole). That may render this solution cumbersome.